# best way to add Entity id & entity types in database

Tags: mysql, database-design, table, entity-framework, eav

we are doing shopping site with **mysql with eav model** to store values.

in below image , 2 types of **entity types** are there under **products_information** table : **1) Mobile 2) T-shirts**

I wanted to know in which table i have to store those `entity types & entity ids`

Is i need to **create new table or adding above 2 columns in existing table ?**

[image]

Comment: [_My comments on EAV._](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav)  There are new features in MariaDB 10.x and MySQL 5.7 that let you store arbitrary attributes in a single column.  This avoids many of the EAV evils.  (I need to update my blog to elaborate.  Maybe I will get to it this week.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make "Entity" an entry in `attributes_list` and treat it as any other attribute.

Also, do the same for "Category" (whatever your categories might be) and drop `Category_details` table